# Problem with getting images from server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to fetch images from url. Can someone point where i get wrong here is my code?

```
NSString *filesContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.projects-demo.com/iphone/xml/Menu.xml"] ];

    DDXMLDocument *ddDoc = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:filesContent options:0 error:nil];
    DDXMLElement *ddMenu = [ddDoc rootElement];
    NSArray *ddChildren = [ddMenu children];

    for (int j = 0 ;j < [ddChildren count]; j++) {
        DDXMLElement *image1st = [[ddMenu elementsForName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cookingType%d",j+1]] objectAtIndex:0];
        for (DDXMLNode *n in [image1st children]) {
        //  if ([[n name] isEqualToString: @"cookingType"]) {
                MenuModel *model = [[MenuModel alloc] init];

                NSLog(@"image of cooking........%@",[n stringValue]);
                model.imgsrc = [n stringValue];
                [listofimages addObject:model];
                //ss
                //======
                NSData *mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:model.imgsrc]];
            NSLog(@"printing    my data ....",mydata);
                UIImage *myimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mydata];
```

I tried to print `nsDAta` but it get nothing.

Comment: Hello Vijay, are you check your url is correct or not? Whats your url?

Comment: NSLog `filesContent` right after the first line, see what you get

Answer (score 1):

Just an observation, your NSLog for the variable myData, misses %@, not sure if this is just a copy and paste error or something that the HTML doesn't show.

Also try and Log [myData length] there might be a problem with the download.

Last, I would recommend that you do all your URL calls asynchronously.

It would look somewhat like this

`
-(void) loadingThumnailFormURL:(NSString *) thumbnailURL {

```
[imageData release];
imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:thumbnailURL]];
NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

[urlRequest release];
[urlConnection start];
```

}`

Needless to say you have to implement the delegate methods for NSURLConnection and capture the data.